# Why do different percentiles give the same value?

Tags: python, numpy, percentile, chi-squared

I was trying to calculate 10 percentiles for a list of chi-squared distributed values. I used "chi-squared" because I think this is closest to what our real data looks like.

Now I was trying to do this step-by-step to don´t miss anything.

```
import numpy as np
values =  np.array([int(w)*10 for w in list(np.random.chisquare(6,1000))])
print('Min: ', np.max(values))
print('Max: ', np.min(values))
print('Mean: ', np.mean(values))

for p in [w*10 for w in range(1,11,1)]:
    percentile = np.percentile(values,p)
    print(p,percentile)
```

This is an example output of the code above:

```
Min:  0
Max:  230
Mean:  55.49
Percent: 10 Percentile:  20.0
Percent: 20 Percentile:  30.0
Percent: 30 Percentile:  30.0
Percent: 40 Percentile:  40.0
Percent: 50 Percentile:  50.0
Percent: 60 Percentile:  60.0
Percent: 70 Percentile:  70.0
Percent: 80 Percentile:  80.0
Percent: 90 Percentile:  100.0
Percent: 100 Percentile:  230.0
```

The point that I´m struggling at is: 
 why do I get the same "Percentile" for 20 & 30 percent?

I always thought that 20 / 30 means: 20 percent of the values lay below the following value (in this case 30). Like with 100 % of the values lay below 230 which is the maximum.

Which Idea am I missing?

Comment: Lesson to be learnt: Test code with different data. Sometimes the data is so special that the code gives output that doesn't seem right, although it is.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because `values` was created with the expression `int(w)*10`, all the values are integer multiples of 10.  This means most of the values are repeated many times. For example, I just ran that code and found that the value 30 was repeated 119 times.  It turns out that, when you count the values, the interquantile interval 20% - 30% contains *only* the value 30.  That's why the values 30 is repeated in your output.

I can break down my data set as

```
   value    #
     0     14
    10     72
    20    100
    30    119
    40    152
    etc.
```

Break this up into groups of 100 (since you have 1000 values, and you are looking at 10%, 20%, etc).

```
                                                np.percentile
Percent  Group       Values (counts)            (largest value in previous column)
-------  ---------   ------------------------   ----------------------------------
10       0 - 99      0 (14), 10 (72), 20 (16)    20
20       100 - 199   20 (84), 30 (16)            30
30       200 - 299   30 (100)                    30
40       300 - 399   30 (3), 40 (97)             40
etc.
```

---

Given the distribution that you used, this output seems to be the most likely, but if you rerun the code enough times, you'll encounter different output.  I just ran it again and got

```
10 20.0
20 20.0
30 30.0
40 40.0
50 50.0
60 50.0
70 60.0
80 80.0
90 100.0
100 210.0
```

Note that both 20.0 and 50.0 are repeated.  The counts of the values for this run are:

```
In [56]: values, counts = np.unique(values, return_counts=True)                                                             

In [57]: values                                                                                                             
Out[57]: 
array([  0,  10,  20,  30,  40,  50,  60,  70,  80,  90, 100, 110, 120,
       130, 140, 150, 160, 170, 180, 190, 210])

In [58]: counts                                                                                                             
Out[58]: 
array([ 14,  73, 129, 134, 134, 119, 105,  67,  73,  33,  41,  21,  19,
        16,   8,   7,   1,   2,   2,   1,   1])
```

Comment: Okay I already assumed it to be something like that! Thanks for your good explanation! In the real data set I also have values between the multiples of ten.

Comment: I changed the values to ```values =  np.array([int(w*10) for w in list(np.random.chisquare(6,1000))])``` and now it looks fine because I don´t only have values that are multiples of ten (like in the real data set).